# Removing git init in my home directory by accident

Tags: git

I ran git init by accident in my home directory on my MacBook. I cannot find the .git file anywhere even when I list all hidden files. I read you can do `rm -rf .git` but was wondering if this would remove all the .git files from my other repos as well in my home directory from other folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.git` folder from the home directory only.

```
rm -rf ~/.git
```

No it won't remove other repos existing in other directories. But in case there was something before, then you didn't do anything extra. It was already there.